# How to create advance search form

Tags: ms-access

I have this code to create multifield search form using MS Access and its refer to syntex error;

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
On Error GoTo errr
Me.infot_subform1.Form.RecordSource = " select * from infot " & BuildFilter
Me.infot_subform1.Requery
Exit Sub
errr:
MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
Private Function BuildFilter() As Variant
Dim varWhere As Variant
Dim tmp As String
tmp = """"
Const conJetDate = "\#dd\/mm\/yyyy\#"
varWhere = Null
If Me.txtID > "" Then
varWhere = varWhere & "[ID] like" & Me.txtID & "AND"
End If
If Me.txtName > "" Then
varWhere = varWhere & "[Name] like" & tmp & Me.txtName & tmp & "AND"
End If
If IsNull(varWhere) Then
varWhere = ""
Else
varWhere = "Where" & varWhere
If Right(varWhere, 5) = "AND" Then
varWhere = Left(varWhere, Len(varWhere) - 5)
End If
End If
BuildFilter = varWhere
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a runtime not compiletime error (otherwise, you would have said what line is being reported as problematic, right?), you aren't including the necessary spaces around keywords. E.g this

```
"[ID] like" & Me.txtID & "AND"
```

will end up with something like

```
[ID] like123456AND
```

That said, I would rewrite BuildFilter to look like this:

```
Private Function BuildFilter() As String
  Dim WhereClause As String
  If Not IsNull(Me.txtID.Value) Then
    WhereClause = "[ID] = " & Me.txtID.Value
  End If
  If Not IsNull(txtName.Value) Then
    If Len(WhereClause) <> 0 Then WhereClause = WhereClause + " AND "
    Dim S As String
    S = Me.txtName.Value
    ' add wildcards if none explicitly specified
    If (Len(S) > 2) And (Left$(S, 1) <> "*") And (Right$(S, 1) <> "*") Then
        S = "*" + S + "*"
    End If
    ' Access SQL allows single as well as double quotes for string literals
    WhereClause = WhereClause + "[Name] LIKE '" + Replace(S, "'", "''") + "'"
  End If
  If Len(WhereClause) <> 0 Then
    BuildFilter = "WHERE " + WhereClause
  Else
    BuildFilter = ""
  End If
End Function
```

1. I've taken out the `LIKE` for `txtID` on the assumption `ID` is numeric, given you didn't wrap it in quote characters in your original code.
2. Conversely, I've added in asterisks for `txtName` given the use of `LIKE` is pointless otherwise.
3. Your use of variants seems a bit confused, so I've removed it.
4. I've made accessing the text boxes' `Value` property explicit, though that's just a personal preference.
5. Whether accessed explicitly or implicitly, `Value` returns a variant that will be `Null` (not an empty string) if the field is blank. Testing for an empty string using `MyVar > ""` is weird anyway, even though formally correct (normally you use `MyVar <> ""` or `Len(MyVar) <> 0`).